# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset with SocketInputStream

Tags: java, servlets, stream

I try to download a file from a URL and save it locally in java. This URL works from my browser but in JAVA, I got these exeception : **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:658)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
```

I tried with different implementations :

**Apache Common IO**:

```
Files.copy(myUrl.openStream(), file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

**Jersey 2** :

```
WebTarget target =ClientBuilder.newClient().target(myUri);
Response response = target.path(ressourcePath).request().get();
```

**Java io** :

```
URL link = new URL(myUri);
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
```

All these examples throw a java.net.SocketException: Connection reset Exception.

I have no control on the server who send the file.

Comment: Can you add the URI you are using?

Comment: Is it possible that your browser is connecting via a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    }
}
```